# Switching between English/Greek

Tags: languages

I want to use in my document both English and Greek characters. I want to alternate between the two languages constantly, as the document is a physics lab report, written in Greek and the symbols  in English.

How can I do that easily, without having to type /selectlanguage{english} every time? I use the babel package for languages and a Greek/English keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you provide some sample code as a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Depending on the set-up it may be appropriate to use macros for the physics expressions, or just introduce a new shorter macro to switch language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both English and Greek language by calling `polyglossia` package and by compiling your document using either `XeLaTex` or `LuaLaTeX` engine. Both of them use your fonts that are in your system, so your only concern is the font you choose to support greek characters. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum} % choose a font that supports greek characters

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\begin{document}

Αυτή η πρόταση ειναι στα ελληνικά, but this one is in english

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which font is that? http://imgur.com/a/sXnRg

Comment: http://www.whatthefont.com

Comment: ?? It's the default Latex font.

Comment: Do you mean computer modern???

Comment: Yeah. But your code doesn't work with Computer Modern and I'm getting really confused.

Comment: as I said in my answer, computer modern must be installed in your system. Probably you have to download it https://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/

Comment: Just mark my answer as a solution :)

Comment: Latex Error : Command \anw@print already defined.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `babel` with the `alphabeta` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}

Αυτή η πρόταση ειναι στα ελληνικά, but this one is in english

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been using the alphabeta package but it gives a weird hyphenation to the capital letters.

Comment: In such cases you need to enclose Greek content in `\foreignlanguage{greek}{ελληνικά}`.

Comment: This is nearly perfect, but it doesn't work with `\usepackage[greek,english,main=greek]{babel}` which makes words like `Contents` translate automatically to `Περιεχόμενα` on the table of contents

Comment: Mixing Greek and Latin script is best done with Xe/LuaTeX and Unicode fonts. Works with both "Babel" or "Polyglossia". The "alphabeta" package is for some Greek symbols/words in non-Greek text, not vice versa. (Read about the limitations in its documentation.)

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Εισαγωγή}
    
    Σήμερα είδα για πρώτη φορά το
    \selectlanguage{english} site
    \selectlanguage{greek}του Γιάννη.
    
    \[
    a = b + \gamma
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you maybe give some more context about your proposed solution? Typically a code snippet alone is not enough to grasp the idea completely.

Comment: For an isolated English phrase, it's better `\foreignlanguage{english}{phrase}` rather than a full language switch. Don't forget the `otherlanguage*` environment for longer passages in the secondary language(s).