# having problems with greek characters in a table using csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple

Hi this is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{Book2.csv}

\end{document}
```

and this is the content of the csv file, i made it with excel and converted with notepad++

```
frequenza ν (Hz),frequenza teorica ν (Hz) ,nodi n
510,537.18,2
760,805.78,3
1010,1074.38,4
1280,1342.97,5
1550,1611.56,6
```

It fails creating the PDF, this is the error message:

```
Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.
Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.12 \csvautotabular{Book2.csv}

? ^C! Interruption.
\GenericError  ...                              #4
                                                    \errhelp \@err@         ...
l.12 \csvautotabular{Book2.csv}
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: A possible solution is to compile with `xelatex` and `polyglossia`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329750/ for an example.

Comment: Thank you, it now creates the pdf with the table, sadly the greek character isn't displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a font problem; with [Gentium](https://software.sil.org/gentium/) and `xelatex` seems to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek, italian, english]{babel}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{Book2.csv}
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image: resulting table]

Comment: solved! Thank you

Comment: Happy to be useful. Please, consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem! https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

For `pdflatex` you can map the ν character in the input to `$\nu$` using `\newunicodecharacter`. However, `csvsimple` does not allow macros in header lines because the header values are used to create keys to refer to the corresponding columns. A workaround for that is to disable the code that creates the keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
% map ν in input to macro
\newunicodechar{ν}{$\nu$}

\makeatletter
% switch off csvsimple column name macros
\def\set@csv@head{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{book2.csv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you don't want to define the character mapping yourself then you can use the `alphabeta` package - note however that the characters look a bit different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\makeatletter
% switch off csvsimple column name macros
\def\set@csv@head{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{book2.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]